# Angular 2 passing parameters to constructor throws DI exception

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I'm wanting to setup a string property on a component in my constructor, but when I try something like this

```
@Component({
    selector: 'wg-app',
    templateUrl: 'templates/html/wg-app.html'
})
export class AppComponent {

    constructor(private state:string = 'joining'){

    }
}
```

I get a DI Exception

```
    EXCEPTION: No provider for String! (AppComponent -> String)
```

Clearly, the injector is trying to find a 'string' provider, and can't find any.

What sort of pattern should I be using for this type of thing? Eg. passing initial parameters to a component.

Should it be avoided? Should I be Injecting the initial string?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `@Input()` properties.

```
<my-component [state]="'joining'"></my-component>

export class AppComponent {
  @Input() state: string;
  constructor() { 
    console.log(this.state) // => undefined
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.state) // => 'joining'
  }
}
```

Constructor should generally be used just for DI...

But if you really, really need it you can create injectable variable [(plunker)](http://plnkr.co/edit/a7itjey8WsEBcINyanQg):

```
let REALLY_IMPORTANT_STRING = new OpaqueToken('REALLY_IMPORTANT_STRING');
bootstrap(AppComponent, [provide(REALLY_IMPORTANT_STRING, { useValue: '!' })])

export class AppComponent {
  constructor(@Inject(REALLY_IMPORTANT_STRING) public state: REALLY_IMPORTANT_STRING) { 
    console.log(this.state) // => !
  }
}
```

Simplest option is to just set class property:

```
export class AppComponent {
  private state:string = 'joining';
  constructor() { 
    console.log(this.state) // => joining
  }
}
```

As @Mark pointed out, another option is to use a service:

```
export class AppService {
  public state:string = 'joining';
}
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private service: AppService) { 
    console.log(this.service.state) // => joining
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, seems like you shouldn't be treating a Component like a regular class

Comment: Well it's not a regular class (: It's a special class that can do some regular things :P

Comment: Heh yeah, I feel like something as straight forward as passing a string should be possible though. I shouldn't need to initialize it in my template

Comment: Yeah I'm more thinking about testability. Being able to pass in some other initial state. Thanks for the answers tho, very comprehensive

Comment: I don't think that REALY_IMPORTANT_STRING example will work as shown.  You need to either create an OpaqueToken, or use a string token and then @Inject it into the constructor.  See [DI dev guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html).

Comment: You might want to mention the one other option I can think of: put the config items in a service (class), and inject that into the component.

Comment: It seems that you misspelled the `console`?